# Circular dependencies and better ways to do it?

Tags: c++, class

I really enjoy coding but currently every project I started has ended early due to the circular dependencies really messing with me and my head. I have been having problems, I am trying to make games, however due to my class structure I rely on some circular dependencies which cause problems in the end that almost always grow and go out of my control. 
How I usually structure it:

1. class Game

   1. class GameContext

      1. class Window

         1. class GameContext
      2. class EventManager

         1. class GameContext
      3. class StateManager

         1. class GameContext

I use this since I sometimes need to access for example the Window from the EventManager. In the end I always seem to lose it. Is there a better way for something like this that avoids circular dependencies? And if not how do you really go about thinking when you have to deal with them? I thought I understood them but clearly not.

What I am trying to archive is a centeral storage "Context" class which other classes could access but I do not know how to avoid circular dependencies in such a case.

To really show what I mean you can look at [THIS](https://github.com/Dequilla/Game/tree/master/Project%20Mystery), my latest failed atempt. 
The problem I have with this current structure seems to be something to do with a dependency between the EventManager and the GameStateManager since in EventManager I get a error on GameStateID being undefined.

Comment: I think you need to try to figure out *why* you "need to" access the Window from the EventManager. What's the EventManager's job? Why does it need a Window for that?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes I'd guess it belongs here, too. Though currently this is too broad / unclear IMO.

Comment: It is not intended to be about codedesign speciallt tailored to games, I just have games as the topic since it is where I use it and get problems. It could be a rocketship which contains a RocketContext that contains a ExhaustManager which need something from RocketContext sometimes.

Comment: @EdwinW. I understand your issue, but I think without a clear problem at hand your question won't be answerable. Perhaps you can try to make a (minimal!) example from the code you linked? You'd then probably get an answer tailored for that specific case, but maybe it helps you to generalize the approach to other cases?

Comment: For example if I pressed a key the window should go fullscreen.

Comment: @DanielJour I understand what you mean, however it is not so much about the code I linked and more the general idea of having a "context" as a centeral storage that every class could access and how you prevent circular dependencies in such a case.

Comment: @EdwinW. Try to incorporate that last comment to your question. That makes it more specific, i.e. about the usage of of a "central context/storage". (IMO one should avoid such a thing as a "central context")

Comment: It looks to me as if you're trying to build your app in a single class hierarchy. You should look into _composition_. I.e. classes reference instances of separate classes that have other responsibilities. That aside all circular dependencies are resolved by extracting a portion of code into a separate location/class that can be shared (without dependency back to origin); thus breaking the circle. The difficult part usually involves identifying the _abstract concept_ that needs to be shared.

Comment: @DanielJour How would be a good way for accessing or changing values that are in other classes then in a case like this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question is too broad. It may help if you edit the question to define a specific circular dependency you're struggling to break.

Comment: @CraigYoung I edited it a little, I do not know if it is enough.

Comment: As an example, you could have lots of things depend on your "context", but you should not allow your "context" to depend on anything else that may lead back to "context". The hierarchy you've shown puts "context" as a subclass which is immediately a problem because sub-classes always ***depend on*** every ancestor in the hierarchy. _NOTE: As powerful as inheritance is, it's a highly restrictive concept and should not be used carelessly. In particular deep hierarchies usually lead poor design._

Comment: @CraigYoung If let's say context contained pointers to all these and nothing else, so that they are all only forward-declared. Would that be a viable structure? Since what I really want is not for context to be dependent on all the other functions but rather a structure to hold all the other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out my problem and it was more in the way of how I thought about it, I thought I wanted a structure like this:

1. class Game

   1. class GameContext

      1. class Window

         1. class GameContext
      2. class EventManager

         1. class GameContext

But what I actually wanted was:

1. class Game

   1. class Window
   2. class EventManager
   3. class GameContext

Where every every class except GameContext contains a pointer to a GameContext.
Also one of my problems was my understanding of forward declaration, I did not understand them and mixed and spread them everywhere because I thought it was magic.

Comment: Usually these problems happen when you create classes without state or to just use them as a bag of functions, you may want to look at this article: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html

Comment: What do you mean with "state"?

Comment: If all functions in a class can be extracted and work as free functions, then your class has no state and it shouldn't be a class at all. A common example you would see online is a "Formatter" class which would contain a function to format something.

Comment: A usual tell is when a class's name terminates with "er", terms like "Manager", "Controller", etc... are very vague. Another article (http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html) Of course you shoudn't follow this rule blindly but it helps you analyse if you really need a class and its purpose.

Comment: @AlexandreBorela Ah, yes it does have A state, nothing in my program is currently without a state, I would not have it as a class if it needed not be. I think some of the things in that article could be a bit of personal preference, but I agree that functions that really don't need a state shouldn't be a class.